# Move Wordpress images all in one folder

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I am currently working with a Wordpress website that has 35GB of images, number of items huge, there are two folders with corrupted images and I can not restore. But, I have all images in one folder as a backup. I can not restore images from backup because I don't know which image belongs to which folder.

Two folders are named based on the yyyy/month/

I was thinking to change all posts date/time into same year and same month and put all images into one folder.

Do you think this will work as solution or you have a better idea.

Note: I have a slow computer this is why I wanted to ask before making a move because each action is taking me couple of hours. Thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to move static content on some static asset hosting service like Amazon S3. It is actually a good practice to store static asset decoupled with the website.

There are some good plugins that you can use for this purpose using which new upload files will be moved to S3 and which automatically changes the URL of the static content.

Please note that the same approach will be followed for videos, audios or any other type of documents.

Hope this will help!